# Display specific product attribute in Woocommerce single product pages below price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

In woocommerce, If a specific product attribute has a value, then I would like to display its corresponding text/value on product single product pages under the price.

How to check if a specific product attribute has a value?
How to get a specific product attribute name and value to display it in single product pages?

Answer (score 3):

The following will display a specific product attribute label name + values under the price in single product pages only if it has a value.

This can be done using [`WC_Product` method `get_attribute()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_attribute).

*You will have to define your product attribute slug inside the function*…

The hooked function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_attribute_after_price', 15 );
function product_attribute_after_price () {
    global $product;

    // HERE add your product attribute SLUG or taxonomy
    $attribute_slug = 'color';

    $taxonomy = strpos($url, 'blog') !== false ? $attribute_slug : 'pa_' . $attribute_slug;
    $attribute_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
    $term_name = $product->get_attribute( $taxonomy ); // The value

    if( empty($term_name) ) return; // Exit if empty value

    // If not empty we display it
    $output  = '<div class="product-attribute '.$taxonomy.'"><p>';
    $output .= '<strong> '.$attribute_name.'</strong>: ';
    $output .= '<span> '.$term_name.'</span>';
    echo $output . '</p></div>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: but how can I define the place to show this? I don't have prices on my single product page. How can I show it below the woo gallery? thanks!

Comment: sorry, this is not my post, so I can't accept the answer. but I did post my own question now. thanks